# Multiple colspan in pdfmake

Tags: html-table, pdfmake

I need the below table structure in the pdf:

[image]

I am using **pdfmake** and tried but unable to achieve the exact structure.

Need some valuable help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will help you

```
var dd = {
           
content: [
{
alignment:'center',
table: {
  widths: ['*','*','*','*','*','*','*',],
  body: [
    [
      {
        text: "",
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
      {
        colSpan:3,
        text:'header 1',
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
      {
        text:'',
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
    {
        text: "",
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
      {
        colSpan:3,
        text:'header 2',
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
      {
        text:'',
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
      {
        text:'',
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
    ],

    [
      {
        text: "S.No.",
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
      {
        colSpan:3,
        text:'item',
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
      {
        text:'',
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
    {
        text: "",
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
      {
        colSpan:3,
        text:'data',
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
      {
        text:'',
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
      {
        text:'',
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
    ],
    [
      {
        text: "1",
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
      {
        text:'item1',
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
      {
        text:'item2',
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
    {
        text: "item3",
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
      {
        text:'data1',
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
      {
        text:'data2',
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
      {
        text:'data3',
        border: [true, true, true, true],
      },
    ],
  ],
},
},


],
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works if you put the "widths" property section.